# linux + list inode information show 100% used

Tags: linux, rhel, disk-usage, inode

we notices about some of our RHEL machines that inode information show `100%`

the following for example show that `/dev/sdb` is 100%

```
df -i
Filesystem                   Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on

/dev/sdc                    2621440  231603  2389837    9% /data/sdc
/dev/sdd                    2621440 2616856     4584  100% /data/sdd
/dev/sde                    2621440 2613251     8189  100% /data/sde
/dev/sdb                    2621440 2621440        0  100% /data/sdb
```

but from `df -h`  `/dev/sdb` is only `65%` used

```
/dev/sdb                     40G   26G   14G  65% /data/sdb
```

what are the options that we have in order to decrease the used of `/dev/sdb` ?

Comment: Remove files from /data/sdb unless I'm missing something. You could move directories with large numbers of files to another drive and symlink or something

Comment: What type of partition / filesystem are concerned ? Are you using one filesystem on unpartitioned disks ?

Comment: its ext4 filesystem

Comment: Since sdc ,sdd… represents devices, you mean you get on single filesystem on an unpartitioned device ? Anyway, the definitive way to get rid of this pb is to backup then rebuild your filesystem with provision for more inodes. (reduce the bytes per inode feature) Grossly if you say 100% inodes used for 65% of blocks used, you could start halving the bytes per inode feature)

Comment: can you give example about --> "rebuild your filesystem with provision for more inodes."

Comment: we build the filesystem with -     mkfs.ext4 -j -m 0 /dev/$disk -F

Comment: See your /etc/mke2fs.conf together with mke2fs.conf manpage. You'll see the feature inode_ratio. I suggest that prior to mke2fs-ing and as part of the appropriate entry, you adjust this value to better suit your needs. (in the example I gave above, dividing the given default value in the mke2fs.conf, you would divide it by 2)

Comment: I checked that -->  inode_ratio = 16384

Comment: Yes ! That's usually the default. Then change it to 8192 (for sdb of course, for sde, sdb other values could possibly better fit) Therefore, rather than changing the default value each time you mke2fs, I invite you to define new entries as part of your mke2fs.conf starting like LABELFOO={ then define your preferences and then mke2fs -T ext4,LABELFOO (together with your other parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the man page for [mkfs.ext4](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4):

> Be warned that it is not possible to expand the number of inodes on a
> filesystem after it is created, so be careful deciding the correct
> value for this parameter.

You have a couple choices.

1. Reduce inodes in use (remove files or directories)
2. Back up the data and recreate the filesystem with more inodes.  (See -i and -I options in man page)
3. Use XFS which has dynamic inode allocation, if you have a lot of small files.

Comment: is it possible to create more inodes with ext4?

Comment: @yael only be formatting it with a new, empty filesystem.

Comment: Well, you can also increase the size of the disk, because the inode count is a ratio to size.  Not as easy for physical systems but OK if it’s a VM.

Comment: so I guess the approach is like  mkfs -t ext4 -N iNumberOfINodes /dev/sdb , but the question is what the max number that we can set on -  iNumberOfINodes  ?

Comment: but maybe the approach - mkfs.ext4 -j -m 0 /dev/$disk -F , takes the max of inodes?

Comment: `mkfs.ext4: too many inodes (99999999999), specify < 2^32 inodes` is what my system says when I use mkfs.ext4's `-N` option. It might be 2^64 on some systems. Note that 2^32 is about 4.2 billion inodes.

Comment: I would suggest using `tune2fs -l /dev/sdb ` and see how many you have now, and calculate how many files you have and how much it will increase, and multiply that by 10, to be safe.

Comment: You don’t want to allocate *too* many inodes because the inode table takes up space on the disk too.

Comment: what you say about  du --inode  /data/sdb | wc -l    in order to count the inode?